# Cant open second hard disk "permission denied"

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive, hardware

I just did a clean install of 13.04 and now cant open any hard disks or hard disk partitions, it says "permission denied". I can open them as root but when I try and change the permissions it says I already have full read and write privileges and wont change the options for group or other users permissions.

The drives are NTFS format, for windows compatibility,while I can get in as root it is a major hassle as all my data is on the second hard drive and I cant add music or video to media players or open text documents without using root.

I know similar question have been asked before and I have tried many solutions but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o uid=<your user id>,gid=<Your group id> <HDD Device Name> <Target Folder to Mount>
```

You can get your user id and group id from /etc/passwd file. This is how my user's entry looks like in my /etc/passwd file. First 1000 is my UID and the second 1000 is my GID.

```
thefourtheye:x:1000:1000:thefourtheye,,,:/home/thefourtheye:/bin/bash
```

If you dont want to execute the mount command each and every time you boot up, just add that command in /etc/rc.local file.