# Mount ext4 partition: “permission denied”

Tags: mount, external-hdd, ext4

I have exactly the same problem as in [Cant open second hard disk "permission denied"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286571/cant-open-second-hard-disk-permission-denied) except that my disk has ext4 filesystem. (don't have enough "reputation" to comment there)

To repeat the problem: I can only write as root.

The corresponding line of /etc/fstab is atm

`UUID=<long stuff> /mountpoint ext4 defaults,rw,user,auto,exec 0 2`

Linked answer doesn't work since `mount -t ext4` doesn't have `-o uid=<...>,gid=<...>` option.

Comment: As far as i know you need to chown your entire disk (while it's mounted) to your user/group.

```sudo chown -R user:group /mountpoint```

Comment: Try changing your `fstab` line to `UUID=<long stuff> /mountpoint ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1` and tell me if this works. After a reboot the disk should already be mounted then at `/mountpoint`

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz works fine, except that it doesn't remember this after reboot.

Comment: @Videonauth I tried it, did not help.

Comment: Please provide the ouput of `ls -l /mountpoint` (you can obfuscate file names).

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz sorry my bad, your answer works now. I am very confused about why it did not work a couple of minutes ago, but now everything is fine. `ls -l /mountpoint` also looks as it should. Thanks everyone.